# RUBY/WATIR/RASTA: Pass the value from the excel/rasta to an array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, excel, watir

How to pass the value separated with comma from the excel/rasta to an array in Ruby.

html looks like this,
....

```
<li><input type="checkbox" name="order:1"  />Burger</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="order:2"  />Pasta</li>
<li><input type="checkbox" name="order:3"  />Fries</li>
```

...

EXCEL looks like this...

**Orders**

Burger, Pasta

---

this code doesnt work

```
attr_accessor :orders

order = [@orders]
order.each do |i|

.......

........
```

---

It should look like this in ruby...

```
attr_accessor :orders

orders = [ 'burger','pasta '] *#should pass data from excel in the array "**orders**"

orders.each do |i|
@browser.checkbox(:text => i).click
@browser.button(:name => 'save').click
end
```

So how would i do the passing of the value in excel to an array?

Sorry, I'm still learning Ruby :|

Comment: What error do you get? In the first example that does not work, you have a variable called order (singular) while in the second example you have a variable called orders (plural).

Comment: im sorry for the variable names,, haha corrected it already but whenever i run the code the error was...... <code><got# <NoMethodError: undefined method 'parent' for : "burger,pasta":String>' <code>

Answer (score 2):

There is a favored library called [roo](http://roo.rubyforge.org). In the linked page, it will tell you how to install the library, then use it to get values out of excel.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'roo'

HOURLY_RATE = 123.45

oo = Openoffice.new("simple_spreadsheet.ods")
oo.default_sheet = oo.sheets.first
oo.first_row.upto(oo.last_row) do |line|
  @browser.check(:value => oo.cell(line,'A'))
  @browser.button(:name => 'save').click
end
```

Answer (score 0):

i can get the values in the excel but i don't know how will I drop them as array in Ruby

My code looks like this.. but it doesn't work

```
......
if array 

 arrayLabel = [:array]

    arrayLabel.each do |i|
    @browser.checkbox(:text => i).click 
    @browser.button(:name => 'save').set
            end


end 
..............
```

---

:array , is the column name where i get the value to be pass in ruby

And also How to do if when the data in the array is not found on the list of checkbos choices?

Comment: Then switch to value because you have spaces in the text.

Comment: I'm sorry there is no value attribute in the form.. :D
Do you have any idea how to make it work?

Comment: They were there when I made my comment. I am not here to solve riddles. I am here to help people. You need to decide what you want.

Comment: in ruby anything starting with a colon such as your ':array' is something called a symbol.   In the code above you are just setting something equal to [:array] (literally)  if you want it reading from a spreadsheet, you need to be calling some method (from a library like Roo) with the column name as a parameter. That method would then read the contents of that column into an array.  You are NOT doing that in the code above.

Comment: BTW in a discussion involving arrays, db columns, etc NAMING a column 'Array' is just going to create very confusing code that is hard to read..  name it for what is in the column such as perhaps "food_item" then what you are doing or trying to do, might make a lot more sense to the people you are asking you to help you.

Comment: if you are providing something as a string value you need to put quotes around it.  without the quotes it is seen as a variable name, and if it starts with a colon, it is seen as a symbol.  and it's STILL a dammed confusing name for a column in the context of this discussion.   Also is there a reason you are doing this via an 'answer' to your question (which does not contain any kind of answer) INSTEAD of just editing the original question?  as the person who asked the question you should see an edit link below it that will allow you to update the question

Answer (score 0):

Find some online tutorials for Ruby, or purchase and work your way through a book like Everyday Scripting With Ruby.

Everyone has to start someplace, but at the moment, it seems you understand so little, and are over-reaching your abilities to the extent that the people who are trying to help you can barely make sense out of your question or what you are trying to do.

Next, work in baby steps, so you can tell what is working and what is failing, and gradually work your way up to what you want to do.

For example, in your case, get the Roo gem installed, and figure out how to use it to read from your spreadsheet and just print stuff on the screen.

Once you can do that, Then try to read the infomation into an array, and print the array out to the screen (so you know stuff got where you need it to go)

Now, write come code using Watir that has values hardcoded to click things etc and fill out the form you are working on etc.

Once you know that is working, combine that with your code to read the spreadsheet into an array, and replace the hard-coded values with stuff pulled from the array that you made from the spreadsheet.