# dump/convert a comma-separated excel data into an array in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, watir

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RUBY/WATIR/RASTA: Pass the value from the excel/rasta to an array in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226539/ruby-watir-rasta-pass-the-value-from-the-excel-rasta-to-an-array-in-ruby)

dump/convert a comma-separated excel data into an array in ruby

html looks like this, ....

Burger

Pasta

Fries

...

---

Do you have any way on how to convert a comma-separated string into an array in Ruby? 
this code doesnt work

```
attr_accessor :orders  

order = [@orders] 

order.each do |i|  
@browser.checkbox(:text => i).click 
@browser.button(:name => 'save').click 
end
```

Got this error whenever I run the above code.

***NoMethodError: undefined method 'parent' for : "burger,pasta":String***

the value in a cell in excel looks like this..with column name "**Orders**"

burger,fries,soda

How would I convert it into an array like this?

```
["burger", "fries", "soda"]
```

---

I can get the data in excel but I don't know how will I convert it to an array in ruby..

**-Sorry I'm new in ruby :D-**

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/10226539/409820 but lacking actual html sample, still just as confusing.  vote to close.

Comment: Is this homework?  Same question format, same example objects.

Comment: no its not an assignment.. :D

Answer (score 1):

This code will split string into an array:

```
'burger,fries,soda'.split(',')
```